# La cookie solo se ve en el localhost

Tags: nodejs, reactjs, cors, localhost, cookies

Hace tiempo vengo teniendo un problema con React y las cookies. El problema es que cuando creo una cookie desde el backend

```
res.cookie('token', token, {
              sameSite: 'none',
              secure: true,
              httpOnly: true
          });
```

En el localhost la cookie se guarda tanto en el back como en el front mientras que cuando despliego la aplicación esta se guarda solo en el backend. En el front la cookie solo aparece cuando recargo un componente o actualizo la página y la puedo ver si hago la petición con el developer tools abierto mientras miro la parte de cookies. Si lo cierro y lo vuelvo a abrir, la cookie ya no la puedo ver, esta de todas formas viaja en los headers (en todas las peticiones de react tengo el credentials include, en el cors también). No sé si también lo tengo que guardar del lado del front con js-cookie o que hacer. Muchas gracias!